# How to download images from array to tableviewcontroller in swift?

Tags: arrays, xcode, image, swift, nsmutablearray

I have a table view controller with a cell that contains an UIImageView. I also have a NSMutableArray that contains the url's. I want the url's to download the images and place them in the correct order. The NSMutableArray also contains some empty Strings and the cell that it corresponds too I want to have my placeholder image from my image assets.

How can I get it to work? I have also populated each cell with a title and summary but cannot workout how images work.

UPDATE

The code used for the image download. Note the photoLabels contains the array of images. Some of the photos are in the incorrect place once the first placeholder image occurs (It is one index late). Why is it doing that. Does anyone know why. I have `println(photoLabels)` and all the 50 strings are correct (with some just being `""`)

If anyone can help that would be great.

```
let imageURL: String = photoLabels.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as String
println(imageURL)
if imageURL == "" {
    cell.imageContainer.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
} else {
    cell.imageContainer.setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: imageURL))
}

return cell
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you confirmed that the index in `photoLabels` array matches, exactly, the indexes in your other arrays holding other pieces of information? As an aside, having a series of separate arrays opens you up to these sorts of disconnects...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! After looking at the json response I get and the actual website they are different. I am still not sure why they were but I recreated the api and everything seems to be working so far. Thanks for all your help and time. :)

Comment: P.S Is what I am doing the best practise for downloading images? From what I have read it seems okay to download them this way. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep, using those `UIImageView` categories is a good away to go, IMHO. It gets you 90% of the way there. Sure, there are always further refinements you could consider (e.g. if the images are high resolution, perhaps resize them to be appropriate for the thumbnail representation in the table; perhaps prefetching images; etc.). But you probably shouldn't worry about those approaches unless you have functional requirement to do so. As they say, "premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemingly innocent question actually entails a rat's nest of interesting details. These include:

- Use lazy loading of the image, loading them just-in-time, rather than trying to download them up front;
- Download the images asynchronously;
- While downloading the images as needed, cache them (using `NSCache`, not `NSMutableArray`) so that if you scroll back to see some images recently downloaded that you don't have to download them again;
- But, in response to memory pressure, make sure to empty the RAM-based cache (but still avail yourself of the persistent storage cache);
- If user scrolls quickly down to the 100th row in the table example, make sure that the images for the visible cells don't get backlogged behind the requests for the previous 99 images (nb: you should test your app in suboptimal conditions, e.g. a poor 2G or 3G cellular environment, which can be simulated with the network link conditioner); and
- You might want a placeholder image to show until the asynchronously retrieved image is downloaded (or retrieved from the cache).

The bottom line is that this takes a non-trivial amount of effort to do properly. As a result, I'd encourage you to use an existing solution, for example the `UIImageView` categories that are available from [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). Both of these two frameworks offer a nice category for `UIImageView` that allows you to request the image to be downloaded asynchronously (it's `sd_setImageWithURL` in SDWebImage; it's `setImageWithURL` in AFNetworking).

Comment: Yes I have done that but when putting the images in the table it is not in order once there are some strings that are empty. I used AFNetworking and everything works but putting the images in the correct order. To be clear, the images are generally in the right order but sometimes they are 1 or 2 spaces out of order. I think it might be something to do with the empty strings that should have my placeholder. Sorry for not being clear. Any suggestions

Comment: My suggestion is that you edit your question with a code sample. How can we advise you on how to fix your code sample without seeing what you've done? I'm hard pressed to imagine how the images could be off if you're using the AFNetworking `UIImageView+AFNetworking` category. You also have to confirm whether the problem is in your networking code, or some mistake in your model objects.